# Get blank page in CI framework

Tags: codeigniter

I have migrate a codeigniter webpage. After I did everything I uploaded and now I am getting a blank page.

I I've done all the things. But even if I have missed something I at least need an indication for that. But I am getting a blank page.

Comment: Make sure error reporting is turned on in PHP. This should then display an error as to what is causing the blank page.

Comment: I enabled error_reporting - nothing

Comment: If i put echo or print_r in the file means it will works, If i removed after I am getting nothing but a blank page.

Comment: Please edit your original question and include the controller code you are using as well as the view you are rendering.

Comment: I have used Version 1.0